# how to programmatically at the end of Navigation of a TWebBrowser autoscroll to desired position

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, twebbrowser

I would like to know how to programmatically at the end of Navigation of a `TWebBrowser` (Delphi XE7) force this one to display the  page from top left corner (some sort of auto scroll). For unknown reason the web browser scroll to the right at end of navigation.

I tried all sort of solutions from the net. `SendMessage` is one of them:

```
SendMessage(WebBrowser1.Handle, WM_HSCROLL, 0 , 0);
```

but none works. Any idea?

Comment: Can you show us how to reproduce this behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple and correct way is to use DOM rather than `SendMessage` to the WebBrowser.
e.g.:

```
var
  window: IHTMLWindow2;

window := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).parentWindow;
window.scroll(0, 0);
```

**Why `SendMessage(WebBrowser1.Handle, ...)` did not work?**

`TWebBrowser.Handle` is not the IE handle you should send messages to. it is a wrapper window (`Shell Embedding`) holding IE window with class name `Internet Explorer_Server`.
Depending on IE version and document mode the structure could be (Use Spy++ to examine the structure):

```
Shell Embedding
  Shell DocObject View
    Internet Explorer_Server <- send message to this window
```

You could use `EnumChildWindows` to find `Internet Explorer_Server`:

```
function EnumChilds(hwnd: HWND; lParam: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
const
  Server = 'Internet Explorer_Server';
var
  ClassName: array[0..24] of Char;
begin
  GetClassName(hwnd, ClassName, Length(ClassName));
  Result := ClassName <> Server;
  if not Result then
    PLongWord(lParam)^ := hwnd;
end;

function GetIEHandle(AWebBrowser: TWebbrowser): HWND;
begin
  Result := 0;
  EnumChildWindows(AWebBrowser.Handle, @EnumChilds, LongWord(@Result));
end;
```

And send messages:

```
IEHandle := GetIEHandle(WebBrowser1);
if IEHandle <> 0 then
begin
  SendMessage(IEHandle, WM_HSCROLL, SB_LEFT ,0);
  SendMessage(IEHandle, WM_VSCROLL, SB_TOP ,0);
end;
```